# not able to wrap commons-logging-1.2.jar using bnd.jar

Tags: logging, osgi, jbossfuse

[image]I am trying to deploy a plain jar - commons-logging-1.2.jar following the documentation given by redhat [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/DeployJar-Convert.html)!

I have attached an image of the error I am getting on command `java -jar bnd.jar wrap commons-logging-1.2.jar`. This command should generate a `.bar` as an output. Where(folder structure) should the `bnd.jar` and `commons-logging-1.2.jar`. be kept?

Comment: seems like, it is because of same source and destination in same place. 
can you try with different in source and destination path.

Comment: `Error: Unable to access jarfile wrap`  if i try to access from some other location.

Comment: yes off course it should say, because classpath might be missing,  just try to set class-path for that jar
 and run   java -jar .... you need to -cp to set jar file location to run this, may be you are missing this.

Comment: You should be able to do this from within the Fuse console. osgi:install wrap:file:<path-to-file>. You can also use a maven uri.